# Extract sub hex from Int with shifting only

Tags: c#, integer, hex

I have a Integer

```
int RBGcolor = 0xAA3080; //R = AA, G = 30, B = 80
```

and I want to extract the `0x30` part, so the result should be `int Output = 0x30;`

How can i do this only with shifting? I thought of something like

```
int Output = RBGcolor>>2<<2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hexadecimal is just a string representation.
An `int` is still 4 bytes. The 3rd byte forms the G part:

```
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
   A        R        G        B
```

Besides R,G & B, a Color also has an A called the Alpha component which indicates transparency.

There are different ways to isolate the different parts:

```
(RGBColor << 8) >> 24 or (RGBColor >> 16) & 0xFF
```

will isolate the R

```
(RGBColor << 16) >> 24 or (RGBColor >> 8) & 0xFF
```

will isolate the G

```
(RGBColor << 24) >> 24 or RGBColor & 0xFF
```

will isolate the B

---

Here is a working example, you have to use `uint`

```
uint RGB = 0xAA3080;

uint R = RGB << 8 >> 24; //170
uint G = RGB << 16 >> 24; //48
uint B = RGB << 24 >> 24; //128
```

Comment: are you sure about R? it's -128 in my case

Comment: If the first bit is 1, right shifting will fill all the shifted bits with 1. I think `(RGBColor >> 16) & 0xFF` is the better option. It will work as it should.